# Как решить эту ошибку в mysql/mariabd?

Tags: mysql, apache, centos, mariadb

Имеется вот такой вот лог, как я понял ошибка в синтаксисе sql, но я даже представить не могу как это решить т.к знаний в серверной части - почти нулевые, поэтому прошу помощи.

```
221023 20:19:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
221023 20:19:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
221023 20:19:52 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.68-MariaDB) starting as process 2318 ...
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
221023 20:19:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
221023 20:19:52  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
221023 20:19:53 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 1597945
221023 20:19:53 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
221023 20:19:53 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
221023 20:19:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
221023 20:19:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
221023 20:19:53 [Warning] Aborted connection 1 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'UNKNOWN_MYSQL_US' host: 'localhost' (init_connect command failed)
221023 20:19:53 [Warning] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’' at line 1
221023 20:19:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
221023 20:19:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
221023 20:19:53  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
221023 20:19:57  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
221023 20:19:57 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

221023 20:19:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *.. for the right syntax to use near '‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’' at line 1* Smart quote chars совершенно недопустимы...

Comment: @Akina, да, знаю, но без понятия где это исрпавить, это где-то в системном файле.... вообще догадок нет